# set 4-bit nibble in an int type

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

we need to come up a method that set a 4-bit nibbles in an int
output should like this:

```
 setNibble(0xAAA5, 0x1, 0); // => 0xAAA1
 setNibble(0x56B2, 0xF, 3); // => 0xF6B2
```

This is what i wrote...

but there have something wrong that I cannot figure out

```
setNibble(FFFF, 0, 0): Expected: FFF0 Result: FF00 
setNibble(FFFF, 6, 1): Expected: FF6F Result:  6FF 
setNibble(1312, E, 1): Expected: 13E2 Result:  E12
```

update: I already put down the code just incase. but basically the answer is really clear and there are so many great answer above.

Comment: Your function operates on 8 bits at a time.

Comment: @zneak this is 4 bits. like 5432|1098|7654|3210 and ints are made of 8 nibbles, right?

Comment: @zneak i got what you mean, so what should i change, i am stuck at this stage.

Comment: I believe this would work, but you've got plenty of people posting answers as well: http://pastebin.com/ZK8RB86G (obviously not tested, as the missing semicolon on the return line should tell you)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were extremely close;

```
    public static int setNibble(int num, int nibble, int which)
    {
        int output;
        if(which ==0)
        {
            output = (num & /*65280*/ 0xFFFFFFF0 ) | nibble;
        }
        else
        {
            int shiftNibble = nibble << (4*which) ;
            int shiftMask = 0x0000000F << (4*which) ;
            output = (num & ~shiftMask) | shiftNibble ;
        }
        return output;
    }
```

In fact, you can simplify the code at the expense of treating case `which == 0` separately.  In fact, you are trading-off an `if` for a shift and a `not`.  Not much difference at all, and the code is much clearer and more elegant.

```
    public static int setNibble(int num, int nibble, int which) {
        int shiftNibble= nibble << (4*which) ;
        int shiftMask= 0x0000000F << (4*which) ;
        return ( num & ~shiftMask ) | shiftNibble ;
    }
```

The idea of the mask is to completely clear the same 4 positions the nibble will occupy in the result.  Otherwise, the position will contain garbage in those bits where the nibble has zeroes.  For example

```
    // Nibble           77776666555544443333222211110000
    num=              0b01001010111101010100110101101010 ;
    nibble=           0b0010 ;  // 2
    which=            3 ;
    shiftNibble=      0b00000000000000000010000000000000 ;
    shiftMask=        0b00000000000000001111000000000000 ;
    num=              0b01001010111101010100110101101010 ;
    ~shiftMask=       0b11111111111111110000111111111111 ;  
    num & ~shiftMask= 0b01001010111101010000110101101010 ;
    //                                  ~~~~  Cleared!
    ( num & ~shiftMask ) 
      | nibble        0b01001010111101010010110101101010 ;
    //                                  ~~~~  Fully set; no garbage!
```

Comment: Your mask is padded with zeroes, not ones. `num & shiftMask` will lose more bits than it should.

Comment: thank. but this code still could not pass some as expected. Like `setNibble(FFFF, 6, 1): Expected: FF6F Result: FF60 Correct: false
setNibble(1312, E, 1): Expected: 13E2 Result: 13E0 Correct: false` the last digit suppose be a alphabet, but it read as 0

Comment: the second part is work! Thanks! But I am still a little bit confuse about the short version (sorry, i am sill in my longer version mode) can you give me some explanation?

Comment: "The idea of the mask is that "...?

Comment: @JavaLeave  If we had kept the `if( which == 0 )`, `nibble` doesn't need to be shifted, and  we could have used a constant instead of computing `shiftMask`.  Final line would have been `return ( num & 0xFFFFFFF0 ) | nibble ;` .

Comment: Binary literals were added to the language in [Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/binary-literals.html).  Who says you can't use `0b` notation?

Comment: @LouisWasserman  Java 1.0, Java 1.1, Java 1.2, Java 1.3, Java 1.4, Java 1.5, and Java 1.6, to mention just a few.  17 years of history or more.  I've been developing in Java for all that time (since Java 1.0.1), and when I'm about to retire they graciously add them to the language.  Same thing with functional programming/closures, and traits in Java 8, which they have been promising for 5?  7 years?  Not to count the mistakes they made with generics, which are just starting to correct.

Comment: @MarioRossi what we can do if we are not allow to use multiplication operator? so (4*which) is not allowed.

Comment: @JavaLeave  `(4*which)` == `which << 2`

Answer (score 3):

This is how I'd do it:

```
public static int setNibble(int word, int nibble, int whichNibble)
{
    int shift = whichNibble * 4;
    return (word & ~(0xf << shift)) | (nibble << shift);
}
```

Let's break it down a bit:

- `shift` is the amount of bits by which you need to shift to place the 4 bits of the nibble at the right position inside the integer. If you want to target nibble 0, `shift` is 0; it's 4 for nibble 1; 8 for nibble 2; and so on.
- `(0xf << shift)` is a binary mask in which there are 1s for each bit the nibble occupies. If you want nibble 1, this will be `0b0000 0000` **`1111`** `0000` (in a 16-bit integer for the sake of brevity).
- `~(0xf << shift)` is the binary mask of bits to **keep** in the original argument. Assuming you want to replace nibble 1 again, this mask is `0b1111 1111 0000 1111`.
- `word & ~(0xf << shift)` clears the bits we're going to replace from `word`.
- `(nibble << shift)` is the binary pattern of the nibble you're setting. If your nibble value is `0b1001`, once shifted, it becomes `0b0000 0000` **`1001`** `0000`.
- The binary or in the middle of the expression combines the initial value, now the bits we want to set have been cleared, with the shifted nibble to come with the final solution.

Comment: there have additional problem for me, if we are not allow to use "*", how can do the shifting job ? thanks

Comment: @JavaLeave, shifting left (`<<`) by N bits is equivalent to multiplying by 2^N. Since 4 is 2^2, shifting left by 2 bits is the same as multiplying by 4. You could do that. (Similarly, shifting _right_ is the same as dividing by 2^N.)

Answer (score 0):

You are shifting your nibble by the wrong amount. You need to shift by 4 bits for every "which"; then you need to replace the bits at that position (first set those bits to zero, then OR with the shifted nibble).  Something like this:

```
shiftIt = 4 * which;
mask = 0xf << shiftIt;
num = num & ~mask;
num = num + (n << shiftIt);
```

You should be able to figure out the details from here.